# Capybara + Rspec Nested Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, nested-resources

Having some difficulties with my Capybara RSPEC testing where I have a nested resource. Here's the error I receive:

> 1) Photo pages visit photo path Photo can be visited after FactoryGirl
>   create records
>        ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mvisit mountain_photo_path(mountain, photo)←[0m
>
> ```
>  ←[31mActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:←[0m
>    ←[31mCouldn't find Photo with id=1 [WHERE "photos"."mountain_id" = 1]←[0m
> ```
>
> ←[36m     # C:in `find'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   ./app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:14:in`show'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   ./spec/requests/photo_pages_spec.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in '←[0m

My nested route is as follows:

```
  resources :mountains do
    resources :photos
  end
```

And I'm testing the following within my RSPEC test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Photo pages" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
    let(:region) { FactoryGirl.create(:region)}
    let(:mountain) {FactoryGirl.create(:mountain)}
    let(:photo) {FactoryGirl.create(:photo)}

    before { sign_in user }

    describe "visit mountain path" do
        it "can be visited after FactoryGirl create" do
            visit mountain_path(mountain)
            page.should have_selector('h1', text: "Breck Test")
        end
    it "has the correct region associated to it" do
        visit mountain_path(mountain)
        page.should have_selector('h4', text: "Rockies")
    end
    end


    describe "visit photo path" do
        it "Photo can be visited after FactoryGirl create records" do
            visit mountain_photo_path(mountain, photo) 
            page.should have_selector('title', text: photo.name)
        end
    end

end
```

I believe FactoryGirl is creating all of the records successfully. The attachment on Photo is done through CarrierWave and after debugging believe this is loading correctly as well.

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name 'Test'
    last_name 'User'
    email 'example@example.com'
    password 'password1'
    password_confirmation 'password1'
    # required if the Devise Confirmable module is used
    confirmed_at Time.now
  end
  factory :region do
    name 'Rockies'
  end
  factory :mountain do
    name 'Breck Test'
    region {|a| a.association(:region)}
    description 'This is my testing mountain only'
  end
  factory :photo do 
    name 'My Photo Test'
    description 'My lovely description'
    mountain {|a| a.association(:mountain)}
    image { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root + 'spec/fixtures/files/breck.jpg', "image/jpeg")}
  end
end
```

I greatly appreciate the wisdom of the group here, thanks in advance for your help. Spent several frustrating hours with this rspec code today, hoping it gets easier in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you create a `mountain`, then a `photo` but they are not related!

Do this instead:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Photo pages" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
  let(:region) { FactoryGirl.create(:region)}
  let(:mountain) { FactoryGirl.create(:mountain)}
  let(:photo)    { FactoryGirl.create(:photo, mountain: mountain) }

  before { sign_in user }

  describe "visit photo path" do
    it "Photo can be visited after FactoryGirl create records" do
      visit mountain_photo_path(photo.mountain, photo) 
      page.should have_selector('title', text: photo.name)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the above code but it is not working, it does not seem to actually create a photo within the FactoryGirl settings. The current FactoryGirl file I thought would relate these two records, it does so successfully between Region and Mountain, which was successfully tested with the code I added to the above description